# Combining delta io and excel reading

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

When using com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0 without delta:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Word Count")
.config("spark.jars.packages", "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0")
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
.option("header", "true")
.load(path2)
```

It works, and I can read excel files fine. But creating a session with configure_spark_with_delta_pip:

```
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("transaction")
.config("spark.jars.packages", "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0")
.config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
.config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

Gives me the following error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o139.load. :
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source:
> com.crealytics.spark.excel. Please find packages at
> http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:692)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:746)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:265)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource at
> java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:666)
> at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:666)
> at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:666)
> ... 14 more

Why? And how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because [`configure_spark_with_delta_pip`](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/master/python/delta/pip_utils.py#L66) overwrites/replaces your config property `spark.jars.packages` whith the appropriate delta lake package to be imported. As such your package `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0` may not be available/imported. See a snippet from the [source code here](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/master/python/delta/pip_utils.py#L66)

> ```py
>     scala_version = "2.12"
>     maven_artifact = f"io.delta:delta-core_{scala_version}:{delta_version}"
>
>     return spark_session_builder.config("spark.jars.packages", maven_artifact)
> ```

Unfortunately at this time, the `Builder` does not allow us to retrieve existing config properties or the [`SparkConf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkConf.html) object to adjust these properties dynamically before calling [`getOrCreate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate) to create or spark session.

### Approach 1

To resolve this you may retrieve the appropriate delta package yourself similar to how [`configure_spark_with_delta_pip`](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/blob/master/python/delta/pip_utils.py#L66) does this eg.

```py
import importlib_metadata
delta_version = importlib_metadata.version("delta_spark")
scala_version = "2.12"
delta_package = f"io.delta:delta-core_{scala_version}:{delta_version}"

builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("transaction")
.config("spark.jars.packages", f"com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0,{delta_package}")
.config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
.config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()
```

### Approach 2

To resolve this you may create the spark session after applying the delta package with `configure_spark_with_delta_pip`. After this, you may trigger the re-initiation of the spark session with the updated config properties.

eg.

```py
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("transaction")
.config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
.config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()

builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("transaction")
.config("spark.jars.packages", "com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.14.0")

spark = builder.getOrCreate()
```

Since both spark sessions have the same `appName` the `getOrCreate` will retrieve the existing spark session but will also apply the new configuration. This behaviour is documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate) as

> In case an existing SparkSession is returned, the config options
> specified in this builder will be applied to the existing
> SparkSession.
>
> ```py
> >>> s2 = SparkSession.builder.config("k2", "v2").getOrCreate()
> >>> s1.conf.get("k1") == s2.conf.get("k1") 
> True
> >>> s1.conf.get("k2") == s2.conf.get("k2") 
> True
> ```

Let me know if this works for you.